# Using set of images as an input

Tags: python, image-processing, wordnet

I am trying to take a set of tagged images as input and remove noisy tags from each image. I have written a python code which takes a text file as input, each line of which corresponds to tags of an image, and removes the noisy tags from each line. I have used the structure and similarity measures in Wordnet to do so.
But i dunno how to take a set of images as input. Could someone please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose you take a bunch of path to images as strings, you can get them as command line arguments or reading them from stdin. Then you just have to open them or do whatever you want with it.

Is that answering your question?

Comment: What if the image set is huge, say thousands of images? And how do i access the tags/annotation of the image from path?